Is there a better way for filtration of liquid tin?
Here is part of my idea for removing an excess of tin from an alloy:
The alloy will be necessary for further experiment, it has not been characterized yet, AFAIK. I believe it will contain robust layer-shaped molecules within tin ($\ce{Sn}$) matrix, not sure how fragmented the layers are. Excess tin (used as a solvent in the exfoliation of a MAX-phase) melts at low enough temperature to be easy to remove by filtering if it is somehow pushed through a filter.
The challenge is to make a suitable filtration apparatus. I consider making a porous clay cylinder and a crucible with the same inner diameter, then placing a weight on top in order to force the tin from the crucible into the pores of the cylindrical filter. After cooling, this filter is broken off and the alloy is ready. The main disadvantage of this method is the uncertainty whether the cylindrical filter size fits perfectly into the crucible without cracking.
Do you know a better method for filtration of liquid tin?
What kind of equipment do I need for this? I do not have access to a well-equipped lab. I hope this part of an experiment can be done at home.

It seems incredible that somebody studies at home special alloys dissolved in liquid metals without any special equipment. Studying alloys needs special equipment, which is expensive, and so is available in well-equipped universities or in industry. What will you do with your alloy at home ? What sort of "further experiment" ?

@Maurice After having spent 11 years of searching the internet and thinking about related stuff every single day, I decided to finally begin to test my understanding. It is not allowed to discuss my theory here, because it is not published or peer reviewed. The "further experiment" involves multiple steps before and after using this tin solvent, and cannot be explained with a brief comment here. Finally, if the properties are as expected, I can give it to somebody who works at an university for further studies. If not, I must admit being completely wrong.

Is it possible for you to describe the molecules "I believe it will contain robust layer-shaped molecules within tin (Sn) matrix" a bit further? Does the sample contain tin as elemental tin, or is the tin chemically bound (like a complex compound) and/or are other compounds (incl. other metals) present (given the relatively low melting point, I thought about zone melting/zone refining)? What is the intended scale of operation and purity?

@Buttonwood Finely powdered MAX-phase https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAX_phases and excess tin, which has to be  mostly removed, but not completely. Batch size is less than 5 cubic centimeters. The purity of tin-rich phase passing through the filter doesn't matter at all -- the fraction left behind must be more tin-rich than MAX-phase and less tin-rich than the initial mix. Not very strict requirement. I will only do this in order to remove enough volume to fit the remaining alloy into a smaller crucible and save time, solvents, and heating costs in the steps that follow later.

If the other metal(s) are dissolved in tin, then as a non-eutectic alloy cools, it separates into two phases -- one tin-rich and other tin-poor.

There will still be tin in the tin-poor phase.
The tin-rich phase still has substantial amounts of the other metal(s).
The two phases are often difficult to separate, forming a sponge-like mass of crystals saturated with an adherent layer of the low-melting phase.


The goal of the filtration is to remove part of the tin alloy. The adherent layer remains, but this is not an issue. The question is, what kind of filter to make.

Not a porous clay cylinder, but a fiberglass fabric. Zetex is a good example, if you can get a sample. Put the fiberglass in a cup in such a way that you can pour your hot melt into it, then grab the fabric top edges, leaving the liquid at the bottom. Close the top edges (I expect you will be wearing protective gloves), and squeeze the liquid thru the fabric.
I have done this with mercury - at room temperature, of course, and it effectively removes dross.
With a semisolid hot metal, this will be slightly more difficult, but way easier than trying to set up a plunger for small quantities, because the technique can be practiced (why not use mercury to practice? different hazards, but easier to do), and can be done swiftly, before everything sets up. (If you practice a lot.)
Other possible fabrics would be fireproof carbon welding blanket, and even cotton, if you're quick, and keep the temperature below about 260ºC. Tin melts at 232ºC, so there's room to work.
